# How to append new row as first row in existing csv file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

When I'm trying to append to CSV file with "ab" option the new row is getting appended at the end of the csv file. But I want the new row as the second row (first row is the header) to the existing CSV file. The csv file is sorted by date in descending order so I want to follow the same fashion.

```
CSV.open(csv_to_update, "ab", {:headers => :first_row }) do |csv|
  csv << [DOJ,name,id,manager,location]
end
```

How can I accomplish it ?

Comment: this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806836/ruby-append-text-to-the-2nd-line-of-a-file

Comment: solution from this link has worked.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file to memory and prepend the line after header with the following :

```
csv_lines = File.readlines(csv_to_update)
new_csv_row = CSV.generate_line([DOJ,name,id,manager,location])
csv_lines.insert(1, new_csv_row)
File.write(csv_to_update, csv_lines)
```